# 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds' when using iloc on idxmax (value should not be out-of-bounds?)

Tags: pandas

I have following code:

```
a_list=[y_list, o_list, r_list]
maks=[]
date=[]
nokl=[]
for the_list in a_list:
    for j in the_list:
        nokl.append(j)
        maks.append((f2021_1[j].max()))
        date.append((f2021_1['ts'].iloc[(f2021_1[j].idxmax())]))
res_l1= pd.DataFrame({'nokl':nokl, 'date':date, 'maks':maks})
```

This results in:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
--> date.append((f2021_1['ts'].iloc[(f2021_1[j].idxmax())]))
```

But, how can this be out-of-bound when trying to find a different columns value for the max of something that is in the dataframe?

f2021_1 is a part of a large df named f2021. When I run the same code on f2021 it works fine, returning a resulting dataframe with date from the 'ts' column. Exactly the same code but different df.

I therefore tried to create f2021_1 by copy() on subset of the large dataframe, but this does not help. I have also tried deep copy without luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's a typo.
You wrote dato.append instead of date.append

Comment: I corrected the typo (thanks), it came from some copy/paste mistake when posting the question. The typo would result in another fault code and does not solve my problem.